# Unique AutoID for each row in google sheet that never changes even if I insert new rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, autonumber

I found this code by searching google (https://blog.cloudstitch.com) and it works but I need to tweak it for two extra things:

1. I need the number to be three digits - where in the code do I set the length?
2. If I insert a row the ID will be a duplicate of the neighbour row.

It is important for me that once the ID has been assigned it will never change.

```
 function AutoID() {

  var AUTOINC_COLUMN = 0;
  var HEADER_ROW_COUNT = 1;

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rows        = worksheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var vals        = worksheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, rows+1, 2);

  for (var row = HEADER_ROW_COUNT; row < vals.length; row++) {
    try {
      var id = vals[row][AUTOINC_COLUMN];
      Logger.log(id);Logger.log((""+id).length ===0);
      if ((""+id).length === 0) {
        // Here the columns & rows are 1-indexed
        worksheet.getRange(row+1, AUTOINC_COLUMN+1).setValue(row);
      }
    } catch(ex) {
      // Keep calm and carry on
    }
  }
}
```

Link to Google Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nN8Iysc-A0cihSvJ-vRse1KDrmNNpj9Zv_y3VYT9S-E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share your spreadsheet

Comment: Spreadsheet is shared now - see link in bottom of post.

Comment: Use UUID / GUIDs. Insert only if the cell is empty. Problem solved.

Comment: Can you help me to change to change the code? - not used to google scripts

Comment: Set the number format using `setNumberFormat(numberFormat)`. For example:         `worksheet.getRange(row+1, AUTOINC_COLUMN+1).setValue(row);` then `worksheet.getRange(row+1, AUTOINC_COLUMN+1).setNumberFormat("000");`

Comment: _If I insert a row the ID will be a duplicate of the neighbour row._ I suggest you rebuild all the IDs on each pass, that will stop duplication.